# Is there a way to ensure that a code only uses names from std, and not the global namespace?

Tags: c++

When using a header which has a format `<cname>`, an implementation will put names into `std` namespace. And it *may* put names into the global namespace as well, as it is described [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/depr.c.headers.other#2):

> [ Example: The header <cstdlib> assuredly provides its declarations and definitions within the namespace std. **It may also provide these names within the global namespace**. [...] — end example ]

Is there a (maybe compiler dependent) way to circumvent/disable this behavior (I'm open to any tricky solution)? I'd like to use names from `std` only, and I'd like to have an error/warning when using names from the global namespace:

```
#include <cmath>

double a = cos(0.5); // I'd like to have an error here, because std:: is missing
```

The reasons:

- It is hard to write a portable code, if it may use names from the global namespace, as these names may be not available in other compilers. It is much cleaner to use everything from `std`, and not use the global namespace at all
- `cos(0.5f)` does a different thing whether `std::` is prefixed or not (`float` vs `double` result).

Comment: With the example of the `cos` function, if you include `<cmath>` and it places `cos` in the global namespace, then `std::cos` and `::cos` are the same function. What is the real problem you have? Why can't you make it a habit to always prefix all standard functions and classes with `std::`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Accidents happen.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: my intent is to verify this habit. I want to prefix std functions all the time, but I'd like to check whether I'm successful using `std::` all the time. Not to mention, for example, `cos(0.5f)`, which does a different thing whether it is prefixed with `std::` or not.

Comment: There is no purely technical solution to this, since any way to reliably cause an error on `a = cos(0.5)` with one compiler but no error on `a = std::cos(0.5)` can be equally reliably (and portably) circumvented with `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 1):

Since tricky solutions are fine...

Use a C++ parser, e.g. Clang, and write a tool that parses the header file, collects all the function definitions, and then compares that set against all definitions and calls to global functions.

Of course, it will also pick up cases where someone has defined or called a function with the same name as the standard ones, but you will probably want to avoid that as well anyway.

Comment: Actually, it is not that tricky, I'm absolutely fine with this. Maybe some lint program already has this functionality. I'll check this out.

Comment: @geza It is tricky compared to, say, switching a compiler flag or using some compiler trick :-) In any case, if I am honest, I wrote that to avoid downvotes from people saying "it is not a C++ solution" and the like ;-) By the way, if you use Clang's Python tooling interface, it should be straightforward.

Comment: A custom clang-tidy check is probably what I'd write for that.